# Can reading VGA signals from my computer harm the hardware?

Tags: oscilloscope, signal-processing, vga

I was really hoping to be able to get (or make) a Y type VGA cable with two outputs and one input.

- The input would be coming from my desktops graphics card
  (specifically an R9 270).
- One output would go to my monitor as normal
- and the other output would be going to a breadboard/oscilloscope
  setup

Im looking to study the signals coming out of them (average values, manipulating the output signal, etc).

Are there any issues with this? Are there any precautions I should take? Any possible ways I could accidentally fry my graphics card or other components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphics cards should tolerate the capacitive load of a wide range of VGA monitors so the additional load of a high impedance (>10 kohm) oscilloscope input will not cause a problem. Take care not to short-circuit VGA signal leads together or to ground. If the branch to the scope is long the horizontal resolution of the display will be degraded by reflection or added capacitance.

If you need to measure risetime, I advise disconnecting the monitor and terminating the VGA signals in 100 ohm at the scope input to match the cable impedance.

Here are the VGA pins: http://www.computerports.net/vga-port/

Answer (score 2):

Splitters are quite simple with VGA- the information only flows one way unless the monitor has an I2C identification channel.

Damage is unlikely, and provided you follow proper procedures there is little that can go wrong. Of course if you accidentally attach any of the VGA wires to something that sends current into the output port, or there is something seriously wrong with the grounding on your oscilloscope etc. bad things **could** happen, as with any direct connection.

Take normal anti-ESD precautions (touch the metal case before touching any connections or use an anti-ESD wrist strap with a high-value internal resistor to earth), make sure the oscilloscope is grounded to earth as the computer, and you should have no problems.

Here's the pinout of a [standard VGA por](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector)t:

[image: http://image.pinout.net/pinout_vga_files/pinout1.jpg]

The timing diagram looks like [this](http://www.xess.com/blog/vga-the-rest-of-the-story/):

[image]

The RGB analog video levels should be in the range of 0 (dark) to 0.7V (full bright). Sync signals are logic level 0V/3.3 or 0V/5V.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're just monitoring the signals and not actively driving them from some other circuitry I don't think you'd have anything to worry about. You might want to google "VGA breakout board" to make your life easier.